I created a aws Elastic Beanstalk instance with a simple express server but only home route is working why so?
so my express server has many routes but only "/" route is working other routes returns can't get type error
.do I need to use proxy for this error to be fixed? or do I need to something else please help. here is the routes of the server
import express from 'express';
const router=express.Router();
import Project from '../models/projects.model.js';
router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('working');
});
router.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const test = new Project({
            name: "manya",
            title: "making portfolio",
            repo: "link to repo",
            tags: ['js', 'reactjs', 'nextjs'],
            img: "link to image",
            liveLink: "not yet live"
        });
        await test.save();
        res.send('done');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`ROUTE ERROR!!! ${error}`);
        res.status(500).send('An error occurred while saving the project.');
    }
});
export default router;

